# Formik FieldArray after upating field (which is used to sort array) array sorts but focus is incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, focus, formik

I'm using Formik's FieldArray to add/remove extra fields of objects from a form. In the objects array, there is a field called position that the array is sorted by when rendering e.g.:

```
<FieldArray name="my_values">
  {({ push, remove }) => (
    values.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position).map(value = etc...
```

For example, if I have two objects:

```
{ name: 'Jane', position: 2 }
{ name: 'John', position: 1 }
```

John will appear first in the form with his name and position field and Jane after. If I update John's position to 3 in the form, Formik will re-render the Form and the Jane and their object's fields will appear first and John after, which is the desired functionality.

The issue is small but I've been stumped at how to solve:

**After sorting again after this position change, I'm focused on the input that's in the first position, which is Jane's position. As I've just edited John's position, I would expect as the user to still be focussed on John's position that now appears below Jane in the FieldArray**

Any ideas on how to "follow" and keep focussed on this field after the array has been sorted?